# Кнопка "Скопировать ссылку" не работает на iphone

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

столкнулся с проблемой, кнопка "Скопировать ссылку" работает на android и помещает url в буфер обмена но на iphone текст кнопки меняется на сам url и копирование не проходит.